# Why does curl -n fail in one script but not others?

Tags: curl, macos, .netrc

Why does curl -n fail in one script but not others?

curl 7.67.0 running on MacOS High Sierra

The following code in one script:

```
host="ftp.xxxxxx.com/public_html/"
/opt/local/bin/curl -n -T $file $host -v
```

Gives me this:

```
> USER xxxx
< 331 User xxxx OK. Password required
> PASS xxxxxxxxxx
< 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
```

The following code in another script:

```
host="ftp.xxxxxx.com/public_html/"
/opt/local/bin/curl -n -T $file $host -v
```

Gives me this:

```
* Couldn't find host ftp.mgnewman.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
<snip>
> USER anonymous
< 331 User anonymous OK. Password required
> PASS ftp@example.com
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0< 530 Login authentication failed
* Access denied: 530
```

Both scripts are bash scripts and located in the same directory of the same machine. There is only one .netrc file. Obviously it is OK as one script uses it with success. The curl code and host variable are the same. In fact, the code in the first script was copied directly from the second script.

How do I figure out why one curl command can use the .netrc file but the other can’t? There must be something in the second script that causes the curl failure, but I have no idea what it might be.

Comment: You may need to use the `--netrc-file` option to specify the path of the .netrc file if different users are using the script.

Comment: Right. I mistakenly changed the $HOME environment variable which prevented curl from finding .netrc.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the records in `.netrc` file. You have it for the first host and not for second host. What you can do is to add such record for second host. The expected format is:

```
machine <host name>
login <user-email or anonymous>
password <user-password or some mail for anonymous access>
```

Depend of the OS the required record can be:

```
machine <host name> login <user-email or anonymous> password <user-password or some mail for anonymous access>
```

Comment: They are both the same host.

Comment: @Buadhai, i read in your log: `Couldn't find host ftp.mgnewman.com in the .netrc file; using defaults` So this mean you do not have record for this site.

Comment: Turns out that the curl error message is misleading. In this case curl couldn’t find the .netrc file because of a stupid mistake I made. Once I fixed that curl was able to find the file. The error message should say something like "Unable to find .netrc file."